# Converse of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a^n\equiv a \pmod n$ for all integers $a$, does this imply that $n$ is prime?

I believe this is the converse of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: Try $n = 561$ or $n = 512461$. These are examples of Carmichael numbers (see the previous comment). The phenomenon is interesting enough to have attracted the attention of many well-known mathematicians.

Comment: and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test#Flaw (but that test is still very useful, for example for RSA keys generation)

Comment: No, carmichael numbers are counterexamples, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2373798/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3467240/242). But there are some valid comverses e.g [that by Lucas](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26145/242)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the converse of Fermat's Little Theorem is not true. For a particular example, $561 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 17$ is clearly composite, but
$$ a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}$$
for all integers $a$. This is known as a [Carmichael Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), and there are infinitely many Carmichael Numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more example: 
We see that $341 = 11 \cdot31$ and $2^{340} = 1\mod341$ 
To show this we see that by routine calcultions the following relations hold $$2^{11} = 2\mod31  $$
$$ 2^{31} = 2 \mod 11$$

Now by using Fermat's little theorem $$ ({2^{11}})^{31} = 2^{11} \mod 31 $$ but $2^{11} = 2 \mod 31$ so I leave you to fill the details of showing $2^{341} = 2 \mod 341$.

Comment: Although this is the standard "Burton counterexample", we should note that it is not *really* a counterexample to Fermat's Little Theorem (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4519823/943723) for details).