# Finding all primes $p,$ such that for all integers $a$, $a^{25} \equiv a\pmod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all primes $p$ such that the following congruence holds for all integers $a$:  $\quad a^{25}\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

I suspect there is a very simple solution, but I can't find it.

Comment: Please [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: Special case of [this Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2373827/242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $a$ is not divisible by $p$, it is equivalent to $a^{24}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

By *lil' Fermat*, this implies that $p-1$ divides $24$.

Comment: LOOL Lil' Fermat xD

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I now see that it holds for every $p$ where $p-1$ divides $24$. But I don't see why it can't hold for some other $p$ as well.

Comment: Because it has to hold for every $a$, and in particular for the generator of the *cyclic* group $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$. This generator has order $p-1$.