# Converse of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Fermat's little theorem states that if $p$ is prime, then $\forall a\in\mathbb N \quad a^p\equiv a \quad \text{mod} \quad p$. Is the converse true ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number

Comment: If memory serves,  you might want to look up _Carmichael numbers_.  They act like primes, but are not.

Comment: See also [Fermat pseudoprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) for the converse notion for fixed $a$.

Comment: No, carmichael numbers are counterexamples, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2373798/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3467240/242). But there are some valid comverses e.g [that by Lucas](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26145/242)