# Prove that for any positive integer $a,$ $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, carmichael-numbers

Prove that for any positive integer $a$, $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}$.
(Hence, $561$ is a pseudoprime with respect to any base. Such a number is called a Carmichael number.)

This obviously works for $1$ but how do I find $2^{561}$ or any other number to the power of $561?$

Comment: I looked at [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467240/show-that-if-an-1-equiv-1-pmodn-for-all-a-such-that-gcdn-a-1) but it didn't really help.

Comment: Factor $561$ and do this for each of the prime factors.

Comment: I factored 561, but what do you mean by "do this for each of the prime factors"?

Comment: We have $561=3\times 11\times 17$.  So, just show that $a^{561}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ for $p\in \{3,11,17\}$.  To get you started:  the case $p=3$ can be done in your head.  And $11$ is only slightly harder.

Comment: All the cases are the same. With $n=561=p_1p_2p_3$ you just need to confirm that $(p_i-1)\,|\,(n-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$a^{561}-a=\left(a^{560}-1\right)a,$$ we see that $a^{561}-a$ is divisible by $a^3-a$, by $a^{17}-a$ and by $a^{11}-a$, which says that it's divisible by $3$, by $17$ and by $11$, which says that it's divisible by $3\cdot17\cdot11=561$.

Comment: How does this show that $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod{561}?$

Comment: @132479 We proved that $a^{561}-a$ is divisible by $3$, by $17$ and by $11$, which says that it's divisible by $3\cdot17\cdot11$,

Comment: How do you know that 5^{561}-a is divisible by a^3-1, a^11 -a, and a^17 -a?

Comment: @132479 $a^{561}-a$ is divisible by $a^3-a$ because $a^{561}-a=a(a^{560}-1)=a(a^2-1)(a^{558}+a^{556}+...+a^2+1)=(a^3-a)(a^{558}+...+1).$ Others are the same.

Answer (score 3):

Fermat's theorem implies that $a^{(p-1)n+1} \equiv a \bmod p$ for all primes $p$, all $a$ and all $n$.

Since $561=3\cdot 11\cdot 17$, apply this to $(p,n)=(3,560/2)$, $(11,560/10)$, $(17,560/16)$.

Comment: Is there something that I need to do after (p,n)=(3,560/2), (11,560/10), (17,560/16)?

Comment: @132479, nothing, except make sure that those fractions are really integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Composite numbers $n>1$, which satisfy $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for all positive integers $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$, are called $\color{red}{\text{Carmichael numbers}}.$**

There is a necessary and sufficient criterion for a positive integer to be a **Carmichael number** known as the **Korselt's criterion**

$\color{red}{\text{Korselt's Criterion:}}$ A positive integer $n>1$ is a Carmichael number if and only if $(1)$ $n$ is square-free, $(2)$ for any prime divisor $p$ of $n$, $p-1\mid n-1$

**Proof:** Try yourself. An easy application of Chinese Remainder Theorem

You can verify, using this criterion, that $561$ is a **Carmichael number**. In fact, there are infinitely many of them.