# Confusion regarding Burton's counterexample to converse of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, examples-counterexamples

Burton's "Elementary Number Theory", Chapter 5 says

> It might be worthwhile to give an example illustrating the failure of the converse of Fermat's Little Theorem to hold, in other words, to show that if $a^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ for some integer $a$, then $n$ need not be prime.

and proceeds to show that $2^{340}\equiv 1\pmod {341}$ after which it comments

> so that the converse to Fermat's Little Theorem is false.

Now, here's my confusion: if we let
$$\text{A: }p \text{ is a prime}\\
\text{B: }a^p\equiv a\pmod p \;\;\forall a\in \mathbb N$$
then (generalized) Fermat's Little Theorem translates to
$$\text{A}\implies \text{B}$$
The converse of this should be
$$\text{B}\implies \text{A}$$
and its negation should be
$$\neg (\text{B}\implies \text{A})$$
or
$$\text{B}\wedge \neg\text{A}$$
which translates to

> $a^p\equiv a\pmod p \;\;\forall a\in \mathbb N$, but $p$ is not a prime.

So, to illustrate that the converse is false, we really need to find a composite $n$ such that $a^n\equiv a\pmod n$ for **all** $a$ and not just one $a$ (as done in the book).

I understand that Burton soon introduces absolute pseudoprimes (or Carmichael numbers) which can be valid counterexamples to Fermat's Little Theorem, but I don't understand how the given "counterexample" does the job. It would be of help if someone has an explanation.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning as well.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647046/converse-of-fermats-little-theorem) for the "converse". I think the statement has a typo here. The quantifiers for $a$ (copime to the exponent is also missing) are missing. Perhaps a translation problem. "For some integer $a$" must be nonsense, because we could just take $a=1$. Or the author wanted to contradict first a weaker statement.

Comment: The given counterexample just shows that a single Fermat-test with a base $a$ satisfying $1<a<n$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1$ is not enough to ensure that $n$ is prime. As you mentioned, it is even not enough that $a^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod n$ holds for every $a$ coprime to $n$ (Carmichael numbers) , but the author wanted to start with the refutation of a simpler statement.