# Why is $120^{128}+1$ a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Wolfram Alpha [says](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=IsPrime%5B120%5E128%2B1%5D) that the number $120^{128}+1$ is prime.  I wonder if that is in fact true, and if so, what is an argument for it.

Thank you for your interest!

Comment: The prime factors of $120^{128}$ are $2,3,5$, and $1$ more than that number would result in the number not being divisible by $2,3,5$. I cannot find a simple way to prove that $120^{128}+1$ is not a multiple of $7,11,13...$

Comment: It's probably using a pseudoprimality test.

Comment: it is under $10^{400},$   you could use Primo for an actual proof certificate

Comment: @Will Jagy: Primo,  will remember that!

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, but ECPP is overkill here because $p-1$ is easy to factor.  OpenPFGW can do it in an instant.

Comment: @orangeskid WolframAlpha can be wrong too?!

Comment: @InanimateBeing: It could be wrong of course. The answer of Greg Martin seems OK. Of course, the numbers are so large that we can only watch the software perform. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @orangeskid I thought for subject as in Maths which is for most part objective and not subjective, I thought that WolframAlpha (WA) is reliable. And in cases where numbers are too large to compute then WA would return an error and not a "wrong" answer. This seems to not be the case as you have asked the question. So, I wondered if that's actually trure?

Comment: @InanimateBeing: In this case I would trust WA. But in principle software can have glitches. I remember some fairly simple definite integral was not given the right result by WA. This is perhaps due to their sophisticated algorithms that failed in some "extreme cases".  I would say in this case we do have a prime number. Hey, maybe you can discover another one in a similar way, for me it was a lucky strike.

Comment: @orangeskid thanks, that was a good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If given the correct command, [WolframAlpha can tell us](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PowerMod%5B22%2C+120%5E128%2F%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+5%7D%2C+120%5E128+%2B+1%5D) that $22$ is a primitive root modulo $120^{128}+1$.

- `PowerMod[22, 120^128/{1, 2, 3, 5}, 120^128 + 1]` computes the list $\{ 22^{120^{128}}, 22^{120^{128}/2}, 22^{120^{128}/3}, 22^{120^{128}/5} \}$ modulo $120^{128}+1$.
- The fact that $22^{120^{128}} \equiv 1 \pmod {120^{128}+1}$ tells us that the order of $22$ modulo $120^{128}+1$ is a divisor of $120^{128}$.
- The fact that $22^{120^{128}/2} \not\equiv 1 \pmod {120^{128}+1}$ tells us that the order of $22$ modulo $120^{128}+1$ is not a divisor of $120^{128}/2$. Similarly, the order of $22$ modulo $120^{128}+1$ is not a divisor of $120^{128}/3$ nor a divisor of $120^{128}/5$.
- Since $2$, $3$, and $5$ are the only primes dividing $120^{128}$, we conclude that the only divisor of $120^{128}$ that is not a divisor of any of $120^{128}/2$, $120^{128}/3$, or $120^{128}/5$ is $120^{128}$ itself.
- Therefore the order of $22$ modulo $120^{128}+1$ is exactly $120^{128}$, which implies that $120^{128}+1$ is prime.

($22$ is simply the first primitive root I found; the smallest three primitive roots are $19$, $22$, and $29$.)

Comment: Nice! I just learned that this is called the Lucas primality test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test

Comment: Very nice, thank you! The order of $a$ is $p-1$, so $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^{\times}$ has at least $p-1$ elements. Now I understand :-)

Comment: @orangeskid This is an instance of the Lucas Primality Test (an *order test*) - which has been discussed here many times in the past, e.g.  [proved here in $2011$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26148/242).

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any public documentation of how WolframAlpha does primality testing. The simplest generally applicable option for numbers this large is the [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test), which for a positive integer $p$ means randomly choosing integers $a \in [2, p-2]$ and testing whether or not $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$. With $p = 120^{168}$ this computation can be done using [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) without too much hassle; the only prime factors of $120$ are $2, 3, 5$ we could do it by repeatedly taking second, third, and fifth powers, and for fifth powers we could use $5 = 2^2 + 1$ to speed the calculation up a bit too.

Unfortunately the Fermat primality test is really a compositeness test; if it finds $a$ such that $a^{p-1} \not \equiv 1 \bmod p$ then $p$ is composite, but if it doesn't then $p$ is only a probable prime. By finding more and more values of $a$ that probability can be driven arbitrarily low but it's still not a proof. There are variants here like the [Solovay-Strassen primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test), the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), or the [Baillie-PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test).

For $p$ such that the prime factorization of $p - 1$ is known we can also apply the test Greg Martin describes which is called the [Lucas primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test), which I just learned about right now. This one really is a primality test: if a number passes then it is provably prime.

Mathematica has a function [`ProvablePrimeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PrimalityProving/ref/ProvablePrimeQ.html) which generates certificates proving that numbers are prime based on [elliptic curve primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_primality); I don't know if this is what WolframAlpha is doing. It might be some heuristic combination of tests depending on what seems like it would be easiest to apply?

**Edit:** [Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#6849) linked to on Wikipedia says that Mathematica's `PrimeQ` function uses a variation of the Baillie-PSW test:

> PrimeQ first tests for divisibility using small primes, then uses the Miller–Rabin strong pseudoprime test base 2 and base 3, and then uses a Lucas test. There are no known composite numbers that pass this procedure.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!

Comment: Miller-Rabin is stronger than Fermat, the implementation is almost the same, and actually runs a tiny bit faster at each step. Importantly there are no known composites that systematically escape it, unlike Fermat.

Comment: I thought the Lucas test requires complete factorisation of p-1 - which is trivial for 120^128+1 and even more trivial for Fermat numbers, but very very hard in general.