# On slightly stronger form of the converse of Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Fom wiki [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), the theorem is as follows:
If there exists an integer $a$ such that
$ a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p $
and for all primes $q$ dividing $p − 1$ one has ${\displaystyle a^{(p-1)/q}\not \equiv 1{\pmod {p}},}$
then $p$ is prime.

How to prove this theorem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews,   I don't know were to begin,  I tried search the net.

Comment: Do you know about Euler's theorem? It says that $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \; (\textrm{mod} \; n)$ for all $a \in \mathbf{Z}$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. Using this and the fact that $\phi(n) = n - 1$ if and only if $n$ is prime, you can prove your theorem!

Comment: @JosephHarrison Yes I know  Euler's theorem.

Comment: @miket have you made any breakthroughs yet?

Comment: @JosephHarrison  Nothing made.

Comment: @miket have you looked at the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/how-to-prove-lucass-converse-of-fermats-little-theorem-without-using-primitive ?

Comment: @JosephHarrison Yes I looked at that answer, but it seems that answer doen't helps.

Comment: @miket If $a^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$, then $\phi(p)$ divides $p - 1$. Writing $p - 1 = k\phi(p)$ for some integer $k$, if $k > 1$ then it is divisible by a prime $q$. Then $(p - 1)/q = k\phi(p)/q$, the latter of which is a multiple of $\phi(p)$ and so $a^{(p - 1)/q} \equiv 1 \mod{p}$, against assumption. Therefore we must have $k = 1$ so that $\phi(p) = p - 1$ and $p$ is prime. I hope this helps! Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @JosephHarrison Thanks, I see.

Comment: @miket awesome :)